# What is the difference between `autoload` and `autoload -U` in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, function

What is the difference between `autoload -U` and plain `autoload`?

For instance, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Help_command) it is recommended to run:

```
autoload -U run-help
autoload run-help-git
autoload run-help-svn
autoload run-help-svk
unalias run-help
alias help=run-help
```

Why is `-U` only in the first line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you do see the recommendation for `-U` often, usually paired with `-z`. It’s not documented in the `run-help` for `autoload`, but there is a section titled “AUTOLOADING FUNCTIONS” in the manpage for `zshmisc`.

There it states:

> The  usual  alias  expansion during reading will be suppressed if the autoload
>   builtin or its equivalent is given the option -U. This is recommended for  the
>   use  of functions supplied with the zsh distribution.  Note that for functions
>   precompiled with the zcompile builtin command the flag  -U  must  be  provided
>   when  the  .zwc  file is created, as the corresponding information is compiled
>   into the latter.

I read that as “disregard aliases”. The `-z` seems to be to avoid Ksh-isms. I just memorize `-Uz` and usually add them to any autoload. Maybe a worthwhile alias: `alias al=’autoload -Uz’`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570749/zsh-completion-difference

Comment: Could you also add some explanation about the option `-z` as well? I barely find any reference on the Internet about what's going on related to "avoid Ksh-isms".

Comment: @Niing the `-z` option loads functions as if the `KSH_FUNCTIONS` option were unset, and the `-k` option loads functions as if it were set, regardless of whether the option is set. That is, `-z` disables "Ksh-style" autoloading, and `-k` enables it. The difference between these two is described in manual [section 9.1 - "Autoloading Functions"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html). Ksh-style basically just `source`s the file, while Zsh-style has some extra behavior that allows the function definition file to also be used as a standalone executable script.

Comment: The `autoload` builtin itself and its flags are documented in [section 17 - "Shell Builtin Commands"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html), and the `KSH_AUTOLOAD` option is documented in [section 16.2.10 - "Shell Emulation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html).

Comment: @shadowtalker: Wow thank you! I just realized that you're the original poster. Sincerely appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Niing I've learned a lot since I first asked this question! Interestingly, I still don't have an answer to why `-U` is _only_ used in the first invocation and not the others. I've been using `-Uz` by default for all of my own functions, because I never want alias expansion during evaluation and I always write Zsh-style function files. `KSH_FUNCTIONS` is disabled by default and I don't enable it in my own config, so `-z` is probably redundant, but it can't hurt either.